# In the backend, can you access data from previous requests?

Tags: django, view, frontend, backend

This is more of a theory question, so I'm not going to post any code.

On the frontend, the user types in a search command. On the backend (Django in my case), it hits an API, the results of the search are saved into a Django View in views.py. On the frontend, the user interacts with this returned data and sends another request. On the backend, is the data from the first Django View still available for use? How do you access it?

(The data is also in the frontend and I can send it with the second request. But if it's still stored on the backend then I wouldn't need to.)

Comment: Nope.  That data is gone, *unless*: you save it to a Database, you store it in cookie(s), or you save it to the cache or user session (ie just more databases).

Comment: If I save it as a cookie, cache, or user-session, these are all on the front-end. Are these basically the same as saving it to state in React instead? (The data doesn't need to stay if the user refreshes or reloads.)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with react, but yeah, probably.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP by it's own nature is a `stateless protocol`. It does mean that protocol doesn't know what or when should happen any request. Request comes and your API just reacts to this request by your implemented logic.

If you want to persist/save any state/data on your API side, you can do it by persisting them to database or saving to any local/global variable. Then you can access this saved state/data while recieving other requests to your back-end and implement the logic to use of previous state with the new incoming data.

Comment: "...or saving to any local/global variable." - Do you save the local/global variable on the frontend or the backend? This is better than saving variables on the View as self.some_var ?

Comment: This was a good answer until the "local/global variable". The very stateless nature of the web means that you *can't* use variables for this, you must use the database.

Comment: Stateless nature of the internet.. Global variables don't work this way. So my 2 choices are save to a database (backend), or save to cookie/session/React state (frontend).

Comment: By saving to local/global variable I meant that saving on back-end side like in-memory db or middleware.